# How to lock the screen to not allow rotate at one fragment

Tags: android, android-sensors, screen-orientation

Having a pager fragment and when one fragment is scrolled in would like it to be lock at portrait mode, and others should allow rotate.

```
override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
    val item = getDataItem(position)   
    if (item is SpecialItem) {

        if (context?.resources?.configuration?.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            activity?.requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT

            // or tried activity?.requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT

           // or tried activity?.requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LOCKED

        }


    } else {
        activity?.requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_FULL_SENSOR
    } 
......
}
```

But after the call of

```
activity?.requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
```

it can still rotate the screen.

What is the right way to lock the screen here?

What is the difference between

```
activity?.requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_FULL_SENSOR
```

and

```
activity?.requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR
```

and

```
activity?.requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_FULL_USER
```

**Update**

Thanks for JensV point out it was a typo and it should be `ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT` there and it is working.

Now the question only what are the difference,  and should it be using

```
activity?.requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LOCKED
```

or

```
activity?.requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT

// or activity?.requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT
```

Comment: Have you verified that the code actually gets called? It looks correct to me on first sight

Comment: it is called I have log to show is called and after the set what is in the activity?.requestedOrientation which is correct.

Comment: I'm guessing it's a typo that you said you wanted to lock to *portrait* mode and then using `SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE` instead of `SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT`?

Comment: ha, @JensV, you're right!!! actually is a typo there, and my log is showing what it has been there which is SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT.  my bad.  btw do you know the difference of the three at bottom? I need to choose one for revert to allow user to rotate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting as an answer as I solved your problem.

Root problem was that `SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE` was being used instead of `SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT`

The answer to your second question: I'd go with `SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED` which will reset back to not having set anything specific.